# When are two kinds of weak equivalence 'the same'?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories

First, an observation: Here are two examples of when different notions of weak equivalence in a category turn out to be the "same":

- (Whitehead's Theorem) Two CW complexes are homotopy equivalent if and only if they are weakly  homotopy equivalent (i.e. there is a map between them which induces an isomorphism on homotopy groups).
- (An 'easy exercise') Two chain complexes of vector spaces are chain homotopy equivalent if and only if they are quasi-isomorphic (i.e. there is a map between them which induces an isomorphism on homology).

In both cases, one direction is immediate, the other direction takes more work. This prompts my questions:

1. **What are other examples of results that share this flavor? i.e. "Two objects are [weakly equivalent in way #1] if and only if they are [weakly equivalent in way #2]."**

and

2. **Is there a result in model category theory which says "Under such-and-such hypotheses, two notions of weak equivalences are the same" so that we can see the two examples above as corollaries?**

*(I'm completely new to model categories, so apologies for any/all naivety.)*

Comment: This is an incarnation of the [Whitehead theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead_theorem#Generalization_to_model_categories) for model categories: a weak equivaience between cofibrant-fibrant objects is a homotopy equivalence. In topological spaces, CW complexes are cofibrant-fibrant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notions of weak equivalence are not 'the same' in your examples, rather they coincide on a certain class of objects, namely those that are 'cofibrant-fibrant' as mentioned in Arun's comment. Perhaps there is a more general question hidden in yours, however, as in both examples you have one notion of homotopy equivalence based on a cylinder or cocylinder functor and therefore feeling somewhat geometric, and one notion of 'quasi-isomorphism' relative to some functor, that I will write as $F$, to another context /  category, $f:A\to B$ being a 'quasi-isomorphism' if  $F(f)$ is an isomorphism. This is then a slightly more general question than yours in the context of model categories and is explored in Baues' work on algebraic homotopy.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. Do weak equivalences always coincide on the class of cofibrant-fibrant objects?

Comment: Have a look at some of the books on Quillen's theory. On fibrant-cofibrant objects a weak equivalence has a homotopy inverse with homotopy given by a cylinder  or cocylinder object (I paraphrase a bit here.) Your question is not quite well posed, as it is not clear what `coincide' refers to.